# Python Multiple Line Terminal Update

Tags: python, windows, terminal

**Short Question**
Is it possible/practical to write and **update** a multi-line (contains `\n`) string on a Windows terminal?

**Background**
I have looked into [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html), but it is Unix only.  I saw a few other Window ports, but it was a bit troubling that Windows XP was an experimental OS for one them.  I am hoping to use this as part of a diagnostic feature to display link status, message rates, etc on a mainly terminal application (note that some variants do have a wxPython GUI input).  That being said, using Cygwin is non-ideal and would love to find a workaround using only the sys module.

I have tried the following: (note that I expected them to fail, but hoped I would be wrong)
Attempt 1: Updates the string but it is all on 1 line

```
sys.stdout.write("\r")
sys.stdout.write("This is a multi-line screen print test") 
sys.stdout.write("Line 1") 
sys.stdout.write("Line 2") 
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Attempt 2:  Does not update but prints all the lines

```
sys.stdout.write("\r")
sys.stdout.write("This is a multi-line screen print test\n") 
sys.stdout.write("Line 1 \n") 
sys.stdout.write("Line 2\n") 
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I could find to **curses** (that has been updated in the last 10 years) was [Windows Console Driver](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm).  Rather than use this approach I went at it was a less elegant method.

```
import os
import time

while(1):
    time.sleep(.05)
    os.system('cls')
    print "This is a multi-line screen print test"
    print "Line 1" 
    print "Line 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the [Windows Console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087.aspx). For example, SetConsoleCursorPosition. Other people appear to have implemented Python modules to support this API: [1](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html), [2](http://ipython.scipy.org/svn/ipython/pyreadline/branches/callback/pyreadline/console/console.py)