# Sys.stdout.write not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, sys

I've got a test script that iterates through two string arrays, and I want to use `sys.stdout.write` to provide the user a simple 'progress bar'.

My current script:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
names  = ['Serv1', 'Serv2', 'Serv3', 'Serv4', 'Serv5']
states = ['Running', 'Stopped', 'Running', 'Running', 'Stopped']
terminated=0
passed=0
for i in range (0, len(names)):
    if 'Running' in states[i]:
        print " [*] stop if running {0} ".format(str(names[i]))
        #service_info(action, machine, names[i])
        terminated+=1
    else:
        print " [!] Passing over {0} ".format(str(names[i]))
        passed+=1
    sleep(2)
    sys.stdout.write(" [ ] {0}/{1} progress left\r".format(i+1, len(names)))
```

The expected output is for the `sys.stdout.write` to keep updating, whilst the print statements are informing the user of some action. But when I run this, the only time `sys.stdout.write` is shown is at the end of the script. E.g.

```
 [*] stop if running Serv1
 [!] Passing over Serv2
 [*] stop if running Serv3
 [*] stop if running Serv4
 [!] Passing over Serv5
 [ ] 5/5 progress left
```

How can I get the progress left to be shown below all of the prints whilst updating?

Comment: those are per line, by default you cant go back to write previous line. one approach is clear the screen and write all line again and again or some windows api. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122775/python-multiple-line-terminal-update

Comment: I have got another script that scans through ports on any host ip address, and it successfully prints and provides a progress output at the same time. I've copied parts directly from it, but it doesn't seem to work in this example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to flush the buffer; all output is buffered; kept in memory until a certain amount of data has been collected, to improve write performance.

The `print` statement flushes that buffer for you, but when writing to `stdout` directly, you need to explicitly flush:

```
sys.stdout.write(" [ ] {0}/{1} progress left\r".format(i+1, len(names)))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Next, you are writing to `stdout` *after sleeping*; the very next thing you do is replace that line with the next `print` statement. Write the message *before* sleeping:

```
for i in range (0, len(names)):
    if 'Running' in states[i]:
        print " [*] stop if running {0} ".format(str(names[i]))
        #service_info(action, machine, names[i])
        terminated+=1
    else:
        print " [!] Passing over {0} ".format(str(names[i]))
        passed+=1
    sys.stdout.write(" [ ] {0}/{1} progress left\r".format(i+1, len(names)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: I've added `sys.stdout.flush()` and it hasn't seemed to make any difference?

Comment: @LukeWillmer: right, you are printing the next message on top immediately. Move the `sleep()` call.

Comment: Ah yeah, seemed I needed `sys.stdout.flush()` as well as the sleep call to be moved. Thanks!

Comment: @LukeWillmer: yes, the flush is definitely a requirement, I just missed that you put the `sys.stdout.write()` somewhere you'd never notice that it did anything. :-)